# Automatically assign command output to a variable in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Is there a hack to encapsulate all commands in a Powershell session so that ***all*** output is tee'd to a temporary variable?

My problem arises when I enter a command `Some-Function`

I'm fully aware of commands like `Tee-Object` and `-OutVariable` that allow me to pipe a function's output to a variable as well as to the console. I could accomplish my goal with the following:

`Some-Function | Tee-Object -Variable PSMyCustomTempVariable`

However, I often don't know or anticipate whether I need the variable until after I've run already run `Some-Function`. In this case, it'd be great to have a variable standing by that contains the output from the last function. This is especially helpful for functions that take a while to run like recursive file searches.

I've looked at [about_Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logging) as well as [Start-Transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript), but these seem to be concerned with recording text to a file; I need the objects returned by the function.

So, is there any way to modify my session so that any Powershell command `Some-Function` basically turns into `Some-Function | Tee-Object -Variable PSMyCustomTempVariable`?

Answer (score 8):

Not exactly. However,

```
$Variable = (Some-Function)
```

will save the output of `Some-Function` in the variable `$Variable`, and allow you to then manipulate the data or pass it to other functions later on. To accomplish the equivalent of

```
Some-Function | Tee-Object -Variable $Variable
```

which would take the output of `Some-Function`, save it in `$variable`, *and* pass it through the pipe to the next command, you could use

```
$variable = (Some-Function)
$variable
```

(or `$variable | Next-Command`), and accomplish what you appear to want.

Comment: Thanks Jeff; this is what I usually end up doing though. I'm looking for something that will assign the variable for me. Maybe a PSReadlineKeyHandler option, I'll check that out.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'assign the variable for me'. What, specifically, is inadequate or unacceptable about this, which is the defined and standard way of doing what you want in PowerShell?

Comment: I'm looking for a hack, not a standard method. The standard method requires a lot of extra typing for a variable I may not need. I'll try to modify the question accordingly.

Comment: I don't see "a lot" of extra typing, but I also find that `($variable = (some-command)) | Next-Command` works as well. Point-blank, ***you are not going to get a 'tee' for this. PowerShell doesn't support it, unless you are going to write your own cmdlet from scratch.***

Comment: OK fair enough :)

Answer (score 0):

The `SetPSReadlineKeyHandler` will work for me. The following code inserts the variable assignment after the end of the line upon pressing `Shift+Enter`.

```
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Chord "Shift+Enter" -Description "Tee function output to `$PSLastVariable"  -ScriptBlock{
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert(" | Tee-Object -Variable PSLastVariable")
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::AcceptLine()
}

Some-Function #{Shift+Enter}
$var = $PsLastVariable
```

One should probably not set this KeyHandler for `Enter` since that would mess with Powershell's multi-line capabilities.